# How do you speed how often MacOS checks dark/light auto appearance

Tags: macos, catalina, dark-mode

I often switch users on my Mac and leave hours between using my iMac and Macbook Pro.

If I leave a Macbook Pro in the day when it's in light mode, then open it at night, it seems to take upwards of 15 mins to notice it should be in dark mode and switch to that. Vice versa in the mornings for dark mode.

Is there a hidden setting somewhere that is the amount of time between checks that MacOS does to see if it should be change it's appearance?

It feels like it checks about every 15 minutes at the moment.